# JOIN adding extra rows in the SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi everyone I Have the below SELECT statement  -- when I run it with without the commented fields I get the correct results (38 rows) but when I uncomment the fields (include them to the query) I get extra rows (about 58 added rows). I would like to know why this is happening if anyone has any idea why? and thank you!

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  R.field ,
  O.field ,
--   CASE
     --WHEN sta.field ='011' THEN ppw.field 
     --ELSE sta.field 
  --END AS field ,
  --CASE
     --WHEN sta.field ='011' THEN pv.field 
     --ELSE sta.field 
  --END AS field ,
  --sta.field AS field ,
  --ppw.field AS field ,
  --sta.field ,
  sta.field,
  V.field ,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(300),R.field ,101) AS field ,
  -- CASE
     --WHEN sta.field ='011' THEN ppv.field 
     --ELSE poh.field 
  --END field ,
  --poh.field ,
  poh.field ,

FROM
    Table1 R
    INNER JOIN Table2 sta
    ON    R.field = sta.field 
    AND   R.field = sta.field 
    AND   R.field LIKE   CASE
                                  WHEN (CHARINDEX('-',field )) > 0
                                  THEN Substring(field , 0, 
(CHARINDEX('-',field ))) + '%'
                                  ELSE field + '%' END
    INNER JOIN Table3 O
    ON      O.field = R.field 
    AND     O.field =
                    CASE
                        WHEN  R.field NOT LIKE '%-%' THEN 
RIGHT(R.field , LEN(R.field ) - 3) + '-0'
                    ELSE RIGHT(R.field , LEN(R.field ) - 3)
                    END                               
    INNER JOIN Table4 V 
    ON V.field = R.field 
    AND V.field = R.field 
    INNER JOIN Table5 poh
    ON         O.field =poh.field 
    AND       O.field = poh.field 
    AND       poh.field = sta.field 
    LEFT JOIN Table6 ppv
    ON ppv.field =poh.field 
    AND ppv.field =poh.field 
    AND ppv.field ='200001'
    LEFT JOIN Table7 ppw
    ON ppw.field ='001'
    AND ppw.field ='02'
    AND ppw.field =ppv.field 
    LEFT JOIN  dbo.Table8 pv
    ON   pv.field ='001'
    AND pv.field =ppw.field 

WHERE
   R.field IN ('001','011')
   AND O.field ='2018-02-28'
   AND R.field ='800155'
   AND poh.field NOT IN ('CPB','CP','C')
   AND poh.field NOT LIKE '9999%'
```

Comment: It's your use of DISTINCT. Your commented fields contain a case statement which could be different. Also, you really shouldn't post your DB schema on the internet.

Comment: Short answer is because of `distinct`

Comment: Also be aware that you have three different columns named "VendorCode" - that may not be the cause of your increased return set but it will cause you problems.

Comment: Side note: Your query is a mess, you should look at converting it to a stored procedure and leverage either temp tables or table variables to do some of those look up the records and then join to those temp tables. For example, your join to dbo.SOSalesTransaction is going to be murder on performance. As a general rule, you should join on indexed fields and never use text comparisons as a join condition.

Comment: Describe what you are trying to do.  Give sample input, expected output, table relationship.  Dumping broken code without description will not help us help you.  Learn how to ask question here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Here is an example of what I was talking about with the query being a mess, it was really bothering me lol. This is just an example but you should be able to see what I'm talking about: https://pastebin.com/1ugyDVnh

Comment: Thanks guys! I appreciate your help. It gave an idea of what needs to be done. I removed my db schema from the internet as suggested by @AdamH.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Brian.

Comment: I will check the link to know how to post a question for future references @Eric